# Using react-native-papper how can I force the default bright theme on device that is set to dark from settings?

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I have an android S22 device that in settings is set to dark.
How can I force the default device light theme independent of the device
This is what I try to do but the paper seams to do nothing even is I set dark = false

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {Provider as PaperProvider, DefaultTheme} from 'react-native-paper';

const App = () => {
  const lightTheme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    dark: false,
  };

  const theme = lightTheme;

  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, marginTop: 20}}>
          Hello there Is this light theme?
        </Text>
      </View>
    </PaperProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I do not want to set any colour values. I just want to use the default sensitive bright and dark values in order to be able to very rapidly prototype but still check that switching theme works properly but I'm having trouble forcing the specific one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const lightTheme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    mode: 'adaptive', // force light theme
  };
```

How about:

```js
 const lightTheme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    mode: 'light',
  };
```

Comment: Still not working. The background is till dark and text white. I need background bright and text dark without specifying the color values myself.

Comment: How about: `  mode: 'light',`